# Modify a file's file stats in C

Tags: c, linux, stat

I am writing a program that improves file portability by merging multiple files into one (much like winzip/7zip).

My question is: is there any way that I can modify the unpacked files' file stats to match the ones before packing? (Not just times.)

Comment: There is no automatic way to achieve this; different filesystems support different attributes. You have to decide, which attributes you want to support, read them (i.e. with `stat()`), write them into your archive in some metadata-section and restore them manually when unpacking them (much like the way `tar` handles this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main directly changeable stats are user and group permissions, which you can change with the `chmod` system call (consult the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chmod)). Actual owner and group can be set with `chown` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chown)) - note that you can only change the owner, or change the group to one for whom the current user is not a member, if running as the superuser (i.e. root). The times can be set with `utimes` ([man](https://linux.die.net/man/2/utime)). Extended file attributes (used for access control lists etc) can be set using `setxattr` ([man](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setxattr)).

Other file attributes - number of hard links, inode, etc - cannot be set directly.

In any case, you will need to read the attributes of the file when you archive it, serialise them into your archive along with the file contents and other metadata, and use the system calls listed to restore them upon extraction.

Comment: Nominally, the preferred call for setting file times is [`utimensat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimensat.html) because it allows you to set the time to nanoseconds (that's the `ns` part of the name).  However, some file systems and operating systems may not support subsecond times on files, and many programs do not use subsecond times when identifying file modification times.